# how can i use subclasses in hibernate for attributes within a table?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following domain objects

```
Loan {
     int id;
     Date attribute1;
}

LoanExtension {
     Date attribute2;
}
```

I would like to keep my objects like this because sometimes I would like to change only the attributes in LoanExtension in my database (i.e. attribute1 in the loan object will be null in the object and i don't want this to get set in the database).

How is this possible using a hibernate mapping with xml? I have done the following

```
<class name="org.domain.borrowerReview.Loan" table="loan_profiles" >
    <cache usage="read-only"/>
    <id name="loanId" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <version name="attribute1" column="date_1/>
    <subclass name="org.domain.borrowerReview.LoanExtension" extends="org.rangde.domain.borrowerReview.LoanProfilesUpdate">
        <property name="attribute2" column="date_2" />
    </subclass>
</class>
```

I'm getting this exception : 
Discriminator is needed when 'single-table-per-hierarchy' is used and a class has subclasses

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/175046/169277

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

You need to add a discriminator column and change the snippet to something like this.

```
<class name="org.domain.borrowerReview.Loan" table="loan_profiles" > 
    <cache usage="read-only"/> 
    <id name="loanId" column="id"> 
        <generator class="native"/> 
    </id> 
    <version name="attribute1" column="date_1/> 
    <discriminator column="loan_profiles_type" type="string"/>
    <subclass name="org.domain.borrowerReview.LoanExtension" extends="org.rangde.domain.borrowerReview.LoanProfilesUpdate"> 
        <property name="attribute2" column="date_2" /> 
    </subclass> 
</class>
```

**Long answer**

First off, do remember that the inheritance in JPA is not an absolute parallel to regular inheritance.

One must evaluate how the design of classes will have an impact on the underlying schema.

You have not mentioned how you would like to have your table structure as.

Hibernate provides three mechanisms for inheritance.

- table per class hierarchy
- table per subclass
- table per concrete class

See detaiils [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html)

Your xml snippet suggests that you are using table per class hierarchy.

Now, if one has subclasses, there would be little use if the is just one subclass (though it is allowed). And under "table per class hierarchy" all the sub classes are placed in the same table.

To distinguish between which subclass a particular record  belongs to, hibernate relies on discriminator column.

You need to define the same.

Refer the following documentation [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html#inheritance-tableperclass).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes I'm using table per class hierarchy (i.e. the attributes in the subclass and the superclass are in one table).

I would be adding more subclasses as I use the object for more purposes within my application.